# Fetch firebase firestore documents with multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore document id array like this

```
ids = ['ddcvsvssdvsdvsdv', 'dvdvvdsvsdvddcds', 'cgcdvgsvgcvdcdcd', ... ];
```

how to fetch all the data of these ids into a single object ?
i can retrieve one document with id like this

`this.firestore.collection('events').doc('bdhfbdhfbdshfbhfb').valueChanges();`

but i don't know how to retrieve with id array

Answer (score 0):

If the array contains 10 or fewer IDs, you can use the `IN` operator to query:

```
let ref = this.firestore.collection('events')
afs.collection('events', ref => 
                         ref.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'IN', ids))
```

If you have more than 10 IDs, you'll have to load them in batches with the same operator, and join the `valueChanges` together.

Comment: Please confirm on what is `afs` in above answer?

Comment: That's AngularFireStore, which is typically used for this type of project. If you're using only the JavaScript SDK, you can just use the `ref.where()` part of my answer.